# Determine the equivalence classes on the relation a - b is in H where H = {4k : k is in Z}

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, equivalence-relations

Let H = {4k : k ∈ Z}. A relation R is defined on Z by aRb if a − b ∈ H.

(a) Show that R is an equivalence relation.

(b) Determine the distinct equivalence classes.

---

A) 

aRa if a - a is in H. Thus a - a = 0 and 0 = 4*m where m = 0. so R is reflexive.

Assuming a - b is in H, we want that b - a is in H. Thus if a - b = c = 4k, b - a = -c = 4(-k) where c is in H. Thus R is symmetric.

Let aRb and bRc, we want to show aRc. Thus if a - b = x and b - c = y, a - c = (x+b)-(b-y) = x + y; where x,y are in H. Thus x+y must also be in H and R is transitive.


B)

Now how would I determine the equivalence classes?

Comment: for symmetric, I would say if $a-b=c=4k$ then $b-a=-c=4(-k)$ is in H

Comment: Just show $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ are distinct under $R$ and every $a\in H$ is in relation with one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use $\sim$ instead of $R$ since this is an equivalence relation. By definition, the equivalence class containing $a\in H$ is 
$$[a] = \{b \in \mathbb{Z} : a\sim b\}$$
Suppose that $b \in [a]$. Then $a\sim b$ which is equivalent to $a-b \in H$. This happens precisely when $a-b = 4k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. That is $b \equiv a \mod{4}$. Thus, $[a] = \{b \in \mathbb{Z} : b \equiv a \mod{4}\}$.